# Can we have more windings on a transformer?

Tags: magnetic-fields

What happens if we put more windings on a transformer?
[image]
Does each winding get a proportional amount of power?
If we put a load also on the primary,does it get some power, too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following applies to an ideal transformer. (In a real transformer there is some energy lost as heat but it is quite small if the transformer design is good).

The primary is energised by the power supply connected to it. A load connected across the primary will draw it's energy only from the power supply, the transformer is not affected by this load.

The primary (ac) current generates an alternating magnetic field in the core. In a perfect inductor the phase of the current is out of phase (at 90 degrees) with the voltage, which means that there is no power drawn from the power supply in generating this field (Power = voltage x in phase current).

The changing magnetic field induces a voltage (EMF) in any secondary winding wound on the same core as the primary. If no *in-phase* current is drawn from any secondary, no energy is drawn from the primary.

If a load is connected to a secondary winding, the in-phase component of the secondary current drawn will result in energy being delivered to the load. The magnetic field in the core due to the primary current is *opposed* by the magnetic field due to the induced current flowing in the secondary winding (in accordance with Amperes Law) and this results in *decreased* changing magnetic flux in the core, which in turn results in decreased "back EMF" in the primary. The primary therefore draws *more* current, which in turn *increases* the primary magnetic field strength (so the **total resultant** alternating magnetic flux in the core stays largely unchanged by drawing secondary current).

The secondary current interacts with the primary winding such that current is drawn in the primary in inverse proportion to the turns ratio of the two windings.

This in-phase current in the primary is drawn from the power supply in accordance with conservation of energy:
Power in = power out.

This is true for all secondary windings wound on the same core so the power drawn from the power supply = the the power drawn from the transformer (sum of all power drawn from all secondarys + losses).
$(V_{Pri} * I_{Pri}) = (V_{Sec1} * I_{Sec1}) + (V_{Sec2} * I_{Sec2}) + (V_{Sec3} * I_{Sec3})..etc + losses$

Comment: _Across_ means _in parallel with._ A load connected in parallel with it will not take any power from it.   e.g.  a heater plugged into the same electrical outlet as a transformer. The mains voltage changes only by the  (hopefully small) IR voltage loss caused by the heater current in the power wires. The transformer will get (very nearly) the same voltage applied to its primary whether the heater is in parallel with it or not.  
A resistor in **series** with the primary is of  course very different and will lower the voltage seen across the primary by the IR loss across the resistor.

Comment: Hi Bob, I would like to answer your question but I don't have enough reputation to add a comment under the question so I'll ask here. I want to clarify what exactly you are meaning by "a load is on the primary". Can you add a diagram showing where the load is to be connected? Do you mean a resistive load?  In parallel with the primary? Or in series with the primary? (If there is current flowing in the primary then there will be a magnetic field in the core).

Comment: Sorry Bob, I understand some stuff quite well but I don't understand SR any more than you (probably less). Certainly not enough to answer your question. I've upvoted it though, seems a good question to me. I'll have a look at your other questions when I get a bit more time. I hope you get an answer that makes sense to you. Cheers :)